# get user id in a plugin without a function

Tags: users

I have an admin page, in the callback of this admin page, i need to query into current user's posts. So let's assume this is my function to add menu page:

```
add_menu_page( 'My billings ', 'Billings', 'manage_options', 'billings', 
'billings_html', 'dashicons-analytics' );
```

And this is the callback function :

```
function billings_html() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $barbershops = new WP_Query( array(
        'author'    => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'barbershop'
    ) );

    print_r( $barbershops ); 

}
```

I need to mention that my code is in plugin. I can't wrap my code to get the ID in a function and run it with an action. As you know, this is the error i get:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() ...
```

I don't know how to get the user id in this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's correct.

just add

```
add_action('init','billings_html');
```

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. `billings_html()` is supposed to be the callback for a settings page. Running it’s output on every page, front *and* back end, doesn’t solve anything.

Comment: That's not right either. That will output the *contents* of the settings page *into* the menu.

Comment: Definitely not. I don't think you really understand how admin menus work.

Comment: nope i just learned wordpress few days back